# Convert bool values to string in json.dumps()

Tags: python, json, boolean

I'm trying to convert a python dict into json, however the API I'm accessing doesn't take bool value instead it uses "true"/"false" string.

Example:

```
dct = { "is_open": True }
json.dumps(dct)
```

currently gives a bool output: `{ "is_open": true }`

but what I want is lower-case string output:
  `{ "is_open": "true" }`

I tried `json.dumps(dct, cls=MyEncoder)` but it doesn't work, only non-native object get passed to MyEncoder default.

```
class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
        def default(self, o):
            if isinstance(o, bool):
                return str(o).lower()
            return super(MyEncoder, self).default(o)
```

Any help would be great.

(Btw this is not my API I'm accessing, so I can't modify the API to access true false value instead of the string alternative.)

Comment: `json.dumps` converts booleans to 'true' or 'false' strings by default.

Comment: Can you include your code and what you are trying to encode a bool to if not 'true' and 'false'...

Comment: Well, "true" and "false" is the boolean representation in JSON, so your problem is vacuous.

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. Don't forget to include the expected and actual output of your program. The code you've posted in incomplete.

Comment: @Jonathan: dumps convert true and false boolean not "true" "false" strings

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That's not possible; those values [are hardcoded into the json module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/json/encoder.py#L364). I think your only option is to modify the output ... ie `replace('true', '"true"')`.

Comment: sup 'true' would replace other element with the word true in it as well. A string for instance.

Comment: @Novel: seems pretty obvious that [`json.load/loads()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) could use an enhance argument  `parse_bool`...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If it were me, I'd convert the Python data structure to the required format and *then* call `json.dumps()`:

```
import json
import sys

def convert(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, bool):
        return str(obj).lower()
    if isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
        return [convert(item) for item in obj]
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {convert(key):convert(value) for key, value in obj.items()}
    return obj

dct = {
  "is_open": True
}
print (json.dumps(dct))
print (json.dumps(convert(dct)))
```

Output:

```
{"is_open": true}
{"is_open": "true"}
```

Comment: So that the Python expression `{True: "yellow"}` becomes the JSON document `{"true": "yellow"}`. Your question doesn't limit the conversion requirement to just dictionary values.

Comment: instead of checking for isinstance of `list` or `tuple` you probably are looking for `collections.Sequence` (PY27) / `collections.abc.Sequence` (PY33+) or even `collections.Sized` / `collections.abc.Sized`; and instead of `dict` you probably want `collections.Mapping` / `collections.abc.Mapping`...